# how to flat maven profiles?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a jar that profile different platforms. The differences (including different dependencies and different version for a dependency) are handled using profile.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>PlatformA</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>PlatformB</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now the problem is, when I build for platform A, the pom that installed is not changed. That means when the jar is used a service, it is need to active the profile PlatformA(or PlatformB) using -PPlatformA. Otherwise, the dependency will not be handled .

So is there a way to flat profile content into the pom and install the flatted pom? That means when using -PPlatformA to build the jar, the pom that installed will not have any profile stuff, just merge the PlatformA content into the pom.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no possibility of "hiding" profile settings.

But you can shorten your profiles, when you use a property for defining the version of a dependency, instead of defining the dependency:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>PlatformA</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <commons-lang.version>2.5</commons-lang.version>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>PlatformA</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
          <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And there is a plugin which helps building artifacts for different platforms without the usage of profiles. Look at [building for multiple environments](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2016/05/08/building-for-multiple-environments/).

Comment: The issue is, when a service uses the jar, the service need to add a profile part in the mvn command line to active the correct profile.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Is the jar build during runtime (production mode) of the "service"? What is the "service"?